# How to get grunt-tslint to generate one pmd file for use in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, pmd, tslint

I have managed to use grunt-tslint to analyse my typescript project. I have a few issues.

By default one output file is created for each input TS file. This fails as the file names for all the output files is the same and saving the second output file fails as the file already exists.
This problem can be avoided by using appendOutput. This appends the output from the analysis of each file to the existing file. With this option one file is produced for the analysis of the entire project.

The problem with this is if you use the pmd formatter talked out in this [post](https://otomato.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/pmd-formatter-for-tslint/). If one file is analysed it's fine. One pmd.xml file is created and is valid. If more than one file is created and you use the appendOutput option you get multiple xml documents with multiple root tags in the same file similar to this:

```
<pmd>content</pmd>
<pmd>content</pmd>
<pmd>content</pmd>
<pmd>content</pmd>
```

(I can't paste actual file content as I can't post from my work PC).
When this file is analysed by jenkins it fails as it is not a valid xml document.

It seems to me like there are a few solutions to this problem:

1. Output a non pmd file (json perhaps) and create a new grunt task to turn that json file into one valid pmd task
2. fix grunt-tslint so that it can output multiple files with different names (looking at the code this wouldn't be too hard from a code point of view)
3. create a grunt task that will fix the broken xml (this could possibly be done with some regular expression find and replace)

Has anyone got any experience with this issue or have any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the tslint pmd formatter. I now recall we also faced the issue you're talking about. I don't quite remember but I think what we finally used was a custom formatter version which wouldn't append `<pmd>..</pmd>` tags to each file violations and some one-liner wizardry to wrap the whole output with these in the end. 
hope this helps

What I'd do is: 
change the [pmd formatter](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/next/src/formatters/pmdFormatter.ts) like this (you can create this as your own formatter ):

```
export class Formatter extends AbstractFormatter {
public format(failures: Lint.RuleFailure[]): string {
   # comment this out
   #let output = "<pmd version=\"tslint\">";
    #insert this instead
    let output ="";
     ...

    #and comment this out
    #output += "</pmd>";
```

And then in jenkins create a shell command step with something like:

```
echo '<pmd version="tslint">'`cat tslint.out`'</pmd>' > tslint.out
```

Please note I'm writing this from memory, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried using grunt-text-replace to remove the root tags but this removes all of them. I can't get it to work with regular expressions either to not remove the first and last. If you could share the one-liner wizardry to wrap the whole file in the root tags that would fix my problem as well I think.

Comment: I edited my answer to include more details. it's not the most elegant solution, but should work ok.

Answer (score 0):

I followed same instruction as specified in above link.
Instead of modifying  pmd formatter ,simple linux commands helped me.
Assuming jenkins_tslint_error directory holds pmd.xml file which contains tslint errors.

Add a  task  in build steps "execute shell script " as

`grunt -f jenkins-tslint`

cd jenkins_tslint_error

sed -i 's|| |g' pmd.xml

sed -i 's|| |g' pmd.xml

sed -i '1s/^//' pmd.xml

sed -i '$a ' pmd.xml

Then use Post-build Actions to capture and use PMD analysis results

Answer (score 0):

I also needed this functionality, so I did it the otherway around and created a fork that allows to output to a custom output directory and extension. My environment utilizes Checkstyle, but with jenkins I am allowed to set a file pattern which can resolve all the xml files from that specified custom output directory (e.g. reports/checkstyle/**/*.xml).

The fork can be found here:

- https://github.com/UXabre/grunt-tslint

I have added it to my packages.json by having a line like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
   ..
   "grunt-tslint": "https://github.com/UXabre/grunt-tslint/tarball/master",
   ..
}
```

In my grunt file I can now specify:

```
tslint: {
    options: {
        outputFolder: 'reports/checkstyle/',
        ext: '.xml',
        formatter: 'checkstyle'
    },
    files: {
        src: "src/**/*.ts"
    }
}
```

I might not be the prettiest of solutions, as it will right all the files in the same folder structure as the pattern that has been inserted; but it does the job for me at least. I will see if I can formalize this into a PR, but for now, you can be the second person on earth to use this!